# Pulling data from an array made in php and passing it to javascript twig

Tags: javascript, json, controller, twig

I am trying to get an array produced in my php controller to pass data to javascript in a .twig file.

I am able to access all the values in a for loop in the .twig but when trying to get the value in javascript, I am only able to get the whole array by using:

`var markers = {{ products|json_encode|raw }};`

This produces:

```
var markers = [{"id":"1","name":"x","location":"San Diego"},{"id":"2","name":"y","location":"LA"}];
```

When trying to access specific values using a for loop within the javascript:

```
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
{ 
alert(markers[i][0])
}
```

Using console.log / alert I get [undefined] for markers[i][0] and [object object] if I loop through markers[i]. The length is correct.

This is my first project using .twig so I don't know if I am just missing something really obvious as I can't seem to find my problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In twig use a data attribute on an element, use a filter to escape any single quotes and then use JSON.parse in Javascript to get the data. There is a good tutorial post here: https://cruftlesscraft.com/passing-data-from-twig-to-javascript#using-a-data-attribute-to-pass-multiple-fields

Comment: Still can't seem to pull any data from the array, only getting "", is it not possible to take the values from `var markers = {{ products|json_encode|raw }};` ?. From the example given `console.log($entryInfoObjects);` shows me the array in console _0: {location: "SD", name: "x"}
1: {location: "LA", name: "y"}_ but the example given `var entryInfo = {
        location: '{{ product.location }}',};` for extracting specific data gives me " "...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your issue lies in the javascript for loop.

Look here:

```
var markers = [{"id":"1","name":"x","location":"San Diego"},{"id":"2","name":"y","location":"LA"}];
```

None of the objects within your array have a property named `0`. You only have properties called `id`, `name` and `location`.

Change your loop to something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
{ 
  alert(markers[i]['name'])
}
```

You should see it shows you the value of each objects `name` property.